# How to pull cell values from Excel document into HTML table with VBA Macro with ForEach Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to create an Excel macro with VBA that generates an HTML table for a weekly webpage update. The table is quite large and several of the table cells are link values. My research has lead me thus far.

```
Sub Export_AB_Table()

  For Each Row In Rows

    valA = ("A" & ActiveCell.Row)
    valB = ("B" & ActiveCell.Row)
    valC = ("C" & ActiveCell.Row)
    valE = ("E" & ActiveCell.Row)
    valG = ("G" & ActiveCell.Row)
    valI = ("I" & ActiveCell.Row)

    tableHTML = "<body><tbody>"
    tableHTML = "<tr><td>"

    valE

    tableHTML = "</td><td>"

    valA valB

    tableHTML = "</td><td>"

    Val

    tableHTML = "</td></tr>"
    tableHTML = "</tbody></body>"

Next table_cell
End Sub
```

I'm wanting to run through the 6 column table and, for each row, pull out several table cell values, inserting them into HTML table row string. The table would then export an HTML doc. I can export the table, it's the pulling values into the table for each row that I can't find a write-up on.

The current issue is my value reference. Can anyone advise or point me in the direction of a tutorial or resource for something close to my desired goal? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about simply creating a new spreadsheet and doing a "Save As" Web Page?

Comment: Yes, but it is a rather wide table and I'm only looking to extract a few pieces of data from each row. Also, some cells are link values, which I'd be plugging into hrefs during this export.

Answer (score 0):

I would't worry about the HTML conversion - let the Excel Save As take care of that.

For links just create the links in the worksheet like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="google.com", _
        TextToDisplay:="google.com"
```

To filter the data, just create a new temporary worksheet, copy only the data you want into it, save it as HTML, then delete it.

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thanks, Charlie.